# Kafka REST Proxy and Creating a Consumer Group per User Session

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am doing some investigation into how we could push realtime updates into a dashboard.

One possibility arose to use the Kafka REST Proxy to expose the underlying Kafka Topics directly via the REST Proxy to an Angular Application for users to subscribe to which could work for our use case.

Given the way that Kafka and the HTTP Proxy works, it seems we would need to create a new "Consumer Group" for each new Session but unsure if this is a good idea now or not.

Does this use case go against the intended use case of the Kafak REST Proxy or is this fine?  Should we be concerned about creating so many Consumer Groups?

Albeit, we are talking about 100's of users and not 100,000s so the actual number of concurrent user sessions here is quite low.